# Dispatching TouchEvents outside your App

Tags: java, android, touch-event

I´m trying to execute an MotionEvent on a remote Phone.
The TouchEvent is obtained on Phone A and send to Phone B.
This is working by now but there is Problem with dispatching that MotionEvent on Phone B.

Here is an example for dispatching a MotionEvent, BUT only on once own View(here Phone A):

```
               long downTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
               long eventTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();

               MotionEvent event1 = MotionEvent.obtain(downTime, eventTime,
               MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN, 100,100, 0);

               MotionEvent event2 = MotionEvent.obtain(downTime, eventTime,
               MotionEvent.ACTION_UP, 100, 100, 0);

               dispatchTouchEvent(event1);
               dispatchTouchEvent(event2);
```

How I am suppose to dispatch an TouchEvent on Phone B when I'm not my own View?
Thx

Comment: No idea of how to do this. Post your solution if there is one. It would be nice to send touch events arbitrarily... imagine all things you could do! Change users password, delete its files, turn of the phone, drive user nuts, etc.

Answer (score 0):

> How I am suppose to dispatch an TouchEvent on Phone B when I'm not my own View?

Fortunately, that is not possible, for obvious security reasons. One application cannot inject events into another application, outside of unit testing (which in turn imposes its own set of restrictions).

Comment: It seems to be possible see "PicMe" or "Droid VNC Server". In both of this apps you are able to execute TouchEvents remotely.

Comment: I found a way that can manage TouchEvents.

http://softteco.blogspot.com/2011/03/android-writing-events-low-level-touch.html

Comment: @Ivo: As the posts indicate, this does not work for Android 2.2 onward, as they closed this security hole.